# Deny direct access to files but allow from index.html

Tags: .htaccess

I have a simple SPA with followed structure:

```
.htaccess
index.html
router.php
temp ┑
     ├─ error.tmp
     ├─ form.tmp
     └─ post.tmp
js ──┑
     └─ m.js
```

How to deny direct access to templates but allow access them from index.html?

This way doesn't helps:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^temp/(.*)\.tmp$ - [F,L]

ErrorDocument 403 /index.html
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

Comment: How are these `.tmp` files being used from `index.html`?

Comment: @MrWhite by `fetch()` from m.js

Comment: Cant you disable access to the files not via rewriteengine, but instead via access control directly?
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html
Uncertain why you would use the rewriteengine for that task.

Comment: @DennisNolte `Deny from all` but `Allow from ...` what?

Comment: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess/
for example (random google first entry)

Comment: @DennisNolte You could use "access control", however, the OP isn't wanting to block _all_ HTTP access, so it's not necessarily any easier doing it that way than using mod_rewrite. (The reference link alone isn't sufficient as that would simply block _all_ HTTP access.)

Comment: @MrWhite looks like there is no approach to protect files from direct access...

Comment: Yes, you can protect files from direct access - as mentioned in my answer. However, it is not 100% reliable, which I've also discussed in my answer. However, you need to state in your question how these files are being accessed - this is crucial to determining how to block access. You've stated in comments that the `.tmp` files are accessed from the client, using JavaScript. What about the other files? If a file doesn't need to be accessed from the client at all then it is trivial to block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mydomain\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^temp/(.*)\.tmp$ - [F,L]
> ```

If you want to deny "direct access" (ie. when the user types the URL directly into the browser's address bar) then you need to remove the first condition that checks whether the `Referer` header is not empty. On "direct requests", the `Referer` is always empty - so the above will not block them.

However, the reason for the condition in "normal" hotlinking protection is because the client may not send a `Referer` even when one is expected. Without that *conditon* then these *legitimate* clients will be blocked also.

> allow access to them from `index.html`

If you specifically only want to allow access from `index.html` and no other client-side file then change the condition to match this *exact* Referer. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=https://example.com/index.html
```

> ...by `fetch()` from `m.js`

However, if you are fetching these resources via an XMLHttpRequest - in which you are constructing the entire HTTP request, then there is no need to check the HTTP Referer (although you could inject a `Referer` header). Instead, you would send a custom header, such as `X-AJAX` (or perhaps override the `User-Agent`) in the request and check for this instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-AJAX} !yes
RewriteRule ^temp/(.*)\.tmp$ - [F]
```

Then set the `X-AJAX: yes` HTTP request header when constructing your XMLHttpRequest.

(No need for the `L` flag in addition to `F`.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example if you are using JS "AJAX".

Comment: There is another internal and external sources files as images, scripts ect. And also I make ajax requests to router.php

Comment: with these rules I get 403:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=https://example.com/index.html [NC]

RewriteRule ^temp/(.*)\.tmp$ - [F,L]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "internal and external sources files"? If you are making ajax requests to other endpoints then you need to modify the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to accommodate these. For static resources like images, CSS etc. then use standard hotlinking and check the HTTP Referer.

Comment: "with these rules I get 403" - What `Referer` header is being sent on the request?

Comment: Referer is `https://example.com/`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=https://example.com/` - works

Comment: Then use that instead. The HTTP Referer is the referring "URL". So, if `index.html` is not present on the "URL" then it should be omitted. Although, what if you were to request `https://example.com/index.html` instead? Or do you block that? Or do you set a custom `Referer` header when making the AJAX request?

Comment: but the files are again accessible via a direct link

Comment: So, in what way did it "work" before? In a direct request, the `Referer` is _empty_. If you only have that one conditon (and the correct regex in the `RewriteRule`) then it can only block direct requests since the condition will be successful. What is the `Referer` header when observing the network traffic under a direct request?

Comment: and there is no `Referer` header in case of file direct request

Comment: Yes, that is correct, there is no `Referer` header on direct requests. This is why I suggested removing the first condition (`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$`). However, you appear to have possibly two different requirements. **1.** Preventing `.tmp` files being called directly - which are called by an AJAX request? **2.** Preventing static resources being called directly.

Comment: For any AJAX request (#1), you should be sending a custom HTTP request header (eg. `X-AJAX`) and checking for this (or the absence of) in order to block access (not the `Referer`), as mentioned in the 2nd part of my answer. The `Referer` is less reliable. For static resources (#2) you need to check the `Referer`, as mentioned in the first part of my answer. Bear in mind that checking the `Referer` is not 100% reliable, as user-agents may simply not send it (for any requests). And this is easy to circumvent - so this is not a "security" thing.